# Laptop - unsupported hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hp-laptop

I have HP ProBook 470 G4. I ordered a Seagate Barracuda Pro Laptop 1TB 7200 RPM hard drive. Then, I saw on my product specifications that my laptop only supports 1TB **5400** RPM hard drive. I had this hard drive before, I just want to upgrade to the faster one. Also, my laptop supports 7200 RPM hard drive with a lower capacity. Why doesn't it support 1TB and is it safe to use it in my laptop? Will it short the PCB or corrupt the hard drive?

HDD info from official HP support website:

```
SATA 7 mm/9.5 mm (.28 in/.37 in), 6.35 cm (2.5 in) hard drives supported

500 GB (5400 rpm) hard drive

500 GB (5400 rpm) SSHD (Hybrid) (8 GB cache)

500 GB (7200 rpm) hard drive

1 TB (5400 rpm) hard drive

2 TB (5400 rpm) hard drive
```

Comment: I think 7200 RPM will work, as long as the power needed to supply the hard disk is there. That is only Rotations per minute. If it does not work I would be very surprised. I would try it out if you can. Let us know if it works out. Thanks

Comment: The disk's rotational speed (5400 RPM / 7200 RPM) is not at all significant with regards to your laptop supporting it. Higher speed disks will typically use more power, but I wouldn't expect that to be an issue for you... Have you actually tried this new hard disk, or are you just presuming that it won't work?

Comment: Does the "_1TB 5400 RPM HDD_" you quote as supported come from a list provided by the manufacturer? If so, I would treat the list as a "_verified and tested support_" list, not a "_this laptop only **only** supports_" list.

Comment: @Attie I'll get the hard drive today and tell you if it works. I'm just confused why it doesn't support the same speed but with a higher capacity.

Comment: As above, it probbaly will support the hard disk you've purchased... just because it's not on a verified / tested list, doesn't mean it will not work.

Comment: I believe that list, found here, https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05272274#AbT4 are the drives you are able to order from HP for the unit.

Comment: @vssher Ok, so those hard drives are "designed" for my laptop but I can use any hard drive?

Comment: As long as the power requirement(s) are there from your system (size matters also, of course). Yes. BIOS should not have a problem just because of speed. HP, if I remember correctly makes they're own hard disks.

Comment: Size is an important factor, but the [1TB Barracuda Pro is 7 or 7.2mm high](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/hdd/barracuda/#specs-2-5), which is the smallest common form-factor (5mm being aimed at ultrabooks).

Comment: @vssher - HP do not make their own consumer hard disks. I'm not even sure that HPE disks are made _by them_...

Comment: @Attie I saw a hard drive from HP a few weeks ago. BTW I got the hard drive now. But I currently don't have my laptop. I'll probably try it tomorrow and tell you if it worked.

Comment: @Attie I've installed the hard drive and it works :)

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer your question with what we've discussed and your findings

Answer (score 1):

The list of hard drives on the HP website is not a list of **supported** hard drives, but a list of hard drives that were tested with the laptop and are recommended for it. The 7200RPM 1TB hard drive works without any problems.